# how would I convert an input of space separated numbers into a list

Tags: python

Very basic question but how would I change a given input of space separated numbers into a list:
e.g.

```
t = input("Enter some numbers: ")
# for example sake the user inputs: 4 5 10 9 8
# I want to then convert these numbers into a list of [4, 5, 10, 9, 8]
```

Comment: yes thanks, i was making it a int first then splitting it, my bad

Answer (score 0):

You can split a string into a list with [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and convert into int.

```py
t = "4 5 10 9 8"  # equivalent to t = input("Enter some numbers: ") with 4 5 10 9 8
print([int(v) for v in t.split(" ")])  # [4, 5, 10, 9, 8]
```